# number of points in a lattice approximation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $L := \{a + bτ : a, b ∈ \Bbb Z\}, τ\in \Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$,

Prove that $n:=Cardinality\{z ∈ L : |z| ≤ x\} ∼ \alpha x^2$ as $x\to \infty$ for some $\alpha  >0$.

I could prove find an upper bound for $n$ of order $x^2$ but couldn't find a lower bound.

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Is this about 'vector-lattices'? Or possibly other lattices tag applies. It doesn't seem to be about 'lattice-orders'.

Comment: Thank you just removed this tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a basis for your lattice. Apply a matrix $A \in GL_2(\Bbb R)$ to the basis vectors to get the lattice spanned by $\{1, i\}$. This changes the asymptotics of the volume by a factor of $\vert \det(A) \vert$. Now the result follows.

Comment: Thank you, I understand for the volume (which is $\pi x^2$) and base change, but how the number of integer lattice point relate to the volume? is it proportional to the volume?

Comment: @Andromeda Yes, they are directly proportional. An explanation: each point in the lattice spanned by $1$ and $i$ is the centre of a square of area one, and counting the squares contained in a circle is a way of approximating the area of a circle.